# How to configure multiple domains, within a single nginx installation to use the same instance of an application?

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I want to a specific folder on multiple domains, under the same nginx installation to use the same instance of a nodejs application.

I have the domains "domain1.com", "domain2.com" and "domain3.com", each with their own static files (only). What I want is that "http://domain1.com/feature" is handled by nodejs and "http://domain2.com/feature" is handled by the same app (memory and stuff) that handles "http://domain1.com/feature".

I don't mind creating another domain/subdomain to handle that, but I do not want to create any redirections (the user that uses domain1 should not be aware that domain2 exists and so on).

Can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the architecture of the application but you may want to proxy it using [nginx's rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), rewriting the URLs to use the same location but sharing the same back end URLs.

Comment: The application is a simple "app.js" written in nodejs (i'm using nginx+passenger). For now, it returns a text file with incremental numbers... Currently, it counts one number on each of the domains. How can I achieve the functionality you mention without letting the user know? I see the "internal implementation" on the link you provided, but I don't see how it works with different domains... Thanks!